# Django case insensitive search in multilevel jsonb field using ORM methods

Tags: python, django, postgresql, jsonb

here is my sample jsonb field:

```json
{
  "name": "XXXXX",
  "duedate": "Wed Aug 31 2022 17:23:13 GMT+0530",
  "structure": {
    "sections": [
      {
        "id": "0",
        "temp_id": 9,
        "expanded": true,
        "requests": [
          {
            "title": "entity onboarding form", # I need to lookup at this level (or key)
            "agents": [
              {
                "email": "ak@xxx.com",
                "user_name": "Akhild",
                "review_status": 0
              }
            ],
            "req_id": "XXXXXXXX",
            "status": "Requested"
          },
          {
            "title": "onboarding", # I need to lookup at this level (or key)
            "agents": [
              {
                "email": "adak@xxx.com",
                "user_name": "gaajj",
                "review_status": 0
              }
            ],
            "req_id": "XXXXXXXX",
            "status": "Requested"
          }
        ],
        "labelText": "Pan Card"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Agentnames": "",
  "clientowners": "Admin",
  "collectionname": "Bank_duplicate"
}
```

In this JSON i need to do case insensitive match for structure->section->request(array)-> title inside each object of request array
I have tried this query filter

```
(Q(requests__structure__sections__contains=[{'requests':[{"title": query}]}]))
```

but it becomes case sensitive. Also i have tried

```
self.get_queryset().annotate(search=SearchVector(Cast('requests__structure__sections', TextField()))
```

which does gives case insensitive result but also lookup among the keys other than title.

also i tried raw sql where i cannot go beyond the request array.

Im expecting any other method or any other approach in django orm that can be used to achieve the require result.

Comment: use 'icontains'  for case insensitive search

Comment: @Jisson Icontains does not works for nested json